# How to get class constant via .GetType()

Tags: c#, oop

I will try to explain.
I have 3 classes : EnemyTeleport, EnemyZigZag, EnemyNormal. They all inherit base class Enemy.
Each of these 3 classes has his own const -> KillPoints.

So in other class. For example Form Class, I need to get these constants.
These EnemyTeleport, EnemyZigZag, EnemyNormal are located in `public Enemy EnemyInstance;`
For example

```
EnemyInstance = new EnemyTeleport();
```

So how can I get Kill Points from EnemInstance? I don't want to to check each possible variant?

Is there smarter way?

Like `EnemInstance.GetType().KillPoints` (doesn't work)

Again. EnemyInstance is Enemy type which holds EnemyTeleport. Constant keeps in EnemyTeleport

Comment: Put KillPoints in the base class. Don't put it in each one.

Comment: You're going to have to be more descriptive than "doesn't work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hierarchy could be defined as follows. Note how `Enemy` class is abstract, while concrete enemies implement property `KillPoints`. Your main implementation has to know only about abstract class `Enemy`, while concrete implementation should be created elsewhere, depending on some flag in your game.

```
public abstract class Enemy
{
    public abstract int KillPoints {get;}
}

public class EnemyTeleport : Enemy
{
    public override int KillPoints
    {
        get{return 6;}
    }
}

public class EnemyZigZag : Enemy
{
    public override int KillPoints
    {
        get{return 10;}
    }
}
```

Now you can take advantage of polymorphic call to  `KillPoints`

```
private Enemy EnemyInstance;

void Main()
{
    EnemyInstance = new EnemyTeleport();

    Console.WriteLine(EnemyInstance.KillPoints);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you expand your base-class Enemy with a property for the KillPoints. In the constructor of a inherited class you can set the KillPoints to the specific value of the certain enemy

But if you don't want to put it into a base-class:

Make the KillPoints as a property in the certain Enemy like:

```
public class TeleportEnemy : Enemy
{
   public int KillPoints{get;private set;}
   public TeleportEnemy()
   {
      this.KillPoints = 666;
   }
}
```

The code to access the Killpoints by an instance of Enemy looks like:

```
Enemy enemy = new TeleportEnemy();
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = enemy.GetType().GetProperty("KillPoints");
        int value = (int)propertyInfo.GetValue(enemy, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use

```
public abstract class Enemy
{
   public abstract List<int> KillPoints;
}
```

For each specific class define the value of `KillPoints` (You can use TemplateMethod pattern to calculate your KillPoints)

link : http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternTemplate.aspx

But in your Main you use base class Enemy for your services

So :

```
Enemy enemy = new EnemyTeleport();
var result = enemy.KillPoints;
```